# Sails.js routes, with variables in url. ex /games/(ID HERE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, sails.js

I have tried to find a guide how to get routes to work with variables in the url
exemple : games/124512 and get that id to controllers in a variable.

My routes.js right now :

```
'/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  },

  '/games/': {
    controllers: 'games',
  }
```

My GamesController.js right now :

```
var GamesController = {

    sayHello: function (req, res) {
        res.view('homepage', {
            user : "sayHello",
        });
    },
    sayWelcome: function (req, res) {
        res.view('homepage', {
            user : "sayWelcome",
        });
    }
};
module.exports = GamesController;
```

I can write /games/sayHello or /games/sayWelcome but what I would like is to be able to write exemple /games/234234 or /games/234234/settings

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set [url slugs](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/URLSlugs.html) in your routes like the link shows, i.e. `/games/:id`. You can access them in your contoller via  by name that you set in the route, i.e. `req.param('id')`

Comment: Thank you! its working fine, but what to write in controller because now I need to write /games/sayHello/(IDHERE), I would like to only need to write /games/(IDHERE)

Comment: set the action option like it shows in the example to sayHello, `action: 'sayHello'` for the `games/:id` route.

Comment: I get this error : Ignored attempt to bind route (/games/:id) to unknown blueprint action (`index`) and i changed sayHello to index..

Comment: Not sure why you would if you're following the example I linked to. Possibly if you named the function index that could be a problem but I also can't see the rest of your code. You can try getting some [help](http://sailsjs.org/#/support) from the sails.js team

Comment: Okey, thanks for all help, I found another way in routes : '/games/:id': 'GamesController.index',
And it worked. :)

Comment: That nice question and answer. but what if I am passing the javascript code instead of id. javascript code executes on the server side or not?